# Easy way to anwser an API with dynamic JSON

Tags: api, json, rest

I'm working on a software who sends request to a distant API which will be develloped by a external party. The Template of the answers the API will  send is known to me so I would like to find a software to anwser my GET request as a placeholder for the upcoming API, and of possible I would like this software to be able to anwser dynamicaly.

I have trouble finding Something fitting for my needs (i have found a small software able to answer static JSON answers). Maybe what i'm looking for is obvious but i have trouble looking for it as English isn't my mothertongue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at nodeJS or python.

See: [this nodeJS tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd)
or [this python tutorial](https://codeburst.io/this-is-how-easy-it-is-to-create-a-rest-api-8a25122ab1f3)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

> Postman is the only complete API development environment, for API developers, used by more than 5 million developers and 100000 companies worldwide.

I have used it for years, and have also looked for alternatives, but have found nothing better.

helpful guide: [How to test your app through Postman](https://nationbuilder.com/how_to_test_your_app_through_postman)